# When using Spring initializer, what version is correct?

Tags: java, spring

The Spring initializer has an option for Java 8, Java 11, and Java 16. I use JDK 15, so which would I choose?

Comment: How can we know which version should you use? whichever you want.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri what is the difference between them?

Comment: @Scrapper142 Java 15 will be EOL at the end of the month. You should probably migrate to Java 16 anyway.

Comment: Aahm... that's going to be one book to write down everything that differentiates those. Please, research yourself. Spring Docs have everything written clearly.. you can also read the release notes to see specifically what are the news per each version.

Comment: The difference is obviously which version of Java the project will run on.... If you need to run it on Java 15, use the first lower version number that's available (for example Java 11).

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca which Java will be EOL? I'd say, it's not correct to say so definitely about which version to go for. OpenJDK and OracleJDK have different lifetimes.. moreover, getting to EOL doesn't make Spring Boot versions deprecated.

Comment: @Scrapper142 please have a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: It's your choice. However, FYI, if you are using Oracle JDK , then JDK 11 is the only LTS version out of these 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring initializer uses LTS(Long Term Support) versions so your application has stable JVM and be updated and patched for a longer period of time compared to others.
I suggest using JDK 16 but it's dependant on your application.

there is 3 option in general:

1. use JDK 16 if you:

- using JDK 12-15 new features
- using features that not deprecated in JDK 16

2. use JDK 11 if you:

- don't use newer features after JDK 11

3. use JDK 8 if you:

- I don't suggest this option because it's too old. if you don't have a reason don't use it.

you can find more details on new features and removals of JDK 16 [here](https://jdk.java.net/16/release-notes)